# I cant solve this error "lateinit property dataBinding has not been initialized"

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

I have base activity< T : ViewDataBinding , VM : ViewModel > extends AppCompatActivity()

and i initialize view binding and view model but when run the app i get this error "**lateinit property dataBinding has not been initialized**"

I don't know what I miss or what the wrong

Below is Base Activity Code

```
open abstract class BaseActivity<T : ViewDataBinding , VM : ViewModel> : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var dataBinding : T
    lateinit var viewModel : VM

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)

        dataBinding = getViewBinding()
        setContentView(dataBinding.root)
        viewModel  = generateViewModel()
    }

    abstract fun getViewBinding(): T
    abstract fun generateViewModel(): VM
```

and this My HomeActivity

```
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityHomeBinding, HomeViewModel>() {

    override fun getViewBinding(): ActivityHomeBinding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)


    override fun generateViewModel(): HomeViewModel {
        return ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        dataBinding.vm = viewModel
          }
}
```

[this is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0GBn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in your base class the `onCreate()` with 2 parameters is not going to get called during the activity's lifecycles. And in your subclass you override the `onCreate()` with a parameter.

Just simple change your base class to override the `onCreate()` with a parameter to fix the problem. And the other thing is you implement these class the java's way.

You can just make it better this way:

BaseClass

```
abstract class BaseActivity<T : ViewDataBinding , VM : ViewModel> : AppCompatActivity() {

    protected abstract val dataBinding : T
    protected abstract val viewModel : VM

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(dataBinding.root)
    }
}
```

Subclass:

```
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityHomeBinding, HomeViewModel>() {

    override val viewModel get() = ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

    override val dataBinding get() = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        dataBinding.vm = viewModel
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` in your `HomeActivity`, the `onCreate` from android's `Activity` is called, but not the `onCreate` from `BaseActivity` - because it expected second param `persistentState`.

So you can do this options to fix the issue:

1. call super method with 2 params in your `HomeActivity`

   ```
   class HomeActivity ... {
   ...
       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState) 
           dataBinding.vm = viewModel
       }
   ```

OR

2. use `onCreate` with one param in your `BaseActivity`

   ```
   open abstract class BaseActivity<T : ViewDataBinding , VM : ViewModel> : AppCompatActivity() {

       lateinit var dataBinding : T
       lateinit var viewModel : VM

       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
          ...
   ```